# Method_missing error when running "rails server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just starting a new rails app but it doesn't let me start the server, after typing 'rails s' the console just pukes me out this;

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fa393f7db20> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/user/Desktop/MiProyecto/Portafolio/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
from /Users/user/Desktop/MiProyecto/Portafolio/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Portafolio>'
from /Users/user/Desktop/MiProyecto/Portafolio/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:9:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

ps: I already ran bundle install and it went out perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in which Rails version you started your application. If by any chance you changed it, upgrading or downgrading it, then, just to be sure, try removing the Gemfile.lock file, adding the "original" Rails version and bundling again.

I reproduced the `'method_missing': undefined method 'load_defaults'` error firstly creating a blank Rails application using the 5.1.3 version, and then changing it to the 5.0.1, removing the Gemfile.lock and running `bundle`.

Comment: This solved it, you were right. Had to delete gemfile.lock then bundle. Thanks a lot !.